# Entity framework - calculate sum field from child records

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm using entity framework core with ASP.NET Core, code first.

In my app I have invoices, with the typical `InvoiceHeader` -> `InvoiceLine` relationship. The `InvoiceLine` entities have a `LineAmount` field, which I want to sum and display on the `InvoiceHeader` when displayed as a list (so I can see the invoice total when viewing the list of invoices).

I'm guessing I'll need to add a `TotalAmount` property to the `InvoiceHeader` entity, with the annotation `[NotMapped]`. But how to most efficiently populate it?

At the moment my `InvoiceHeaderController.Index()` is:

```
    // GET: InvoiceHeaders
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        ApplicationUser appUser = ConstantData.GetApplicationUser(_context, _userManager.GetUserId(User));
        var applicationDbContext = _context.InvoiceHeader.Include(i => i.Customer).Include(i => i.CustomerBranch)
            .Where(i => i.CustomerID == appUser.CustomerID);
        return View(await applicationDbContext.ToListAsync());
    }
```

Can anyone tell me what the most efficient way is to calculate (sum) this `TotalAmount` property?

Thanks.

Comment: Your data model should not contain that property. Use a view model with it. And you can just use a linq `.Sum()` to get the total.

Comment: you have Line Amount field in InvoiceLine  and you have one CustomerID  field already in InvoiceHeader. you have to populate sum of Line amount as per customer in Invoiceheader controller right ?

Comment: @StephenMuecke: actually, it depends. Sometimes it is useful to pre-calculate total amount and store it in "header" - it's just faster to retrieve, when you don't need details. Sometimes this could be used to verify data integrity (some sort of audit). Of course, this has its own cons.

Comment: @Saneeshkunjunni: The CustomerID isnt really relevant here. Thats just the ID of the customer this invoice is for. A customer can have multiple invoices, and in that case, each invoice for a customer would have a different total

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Thanks. I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting sum as separate field you need to create new model class as shown below

```
public class InvoiceHeaderModel{
   public InvoiceHeader invoiceHeader{get;set;}
   public decimal TotalAmount {get;set;}
}
```

and make change in action as

```
// GET: InvoiceHeaders
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    ApplicationUser appUser = ConstantData.GetApplicationUser(_context, _userManager.GetUserId(User));
    var applicationDbContext =await _context.InvoiceHeader.Where(i =>i.CustomerID == appUser.CustomerID).ToListAsync();
    var data = applicationDbContext.Aggregate( new List<InvoiceHeaderModel>(),(invoiceHeaderModellist, it)=>{ invoiceHeaderModellist.Add(new InvoiceHeaderModel(){ InvoiceHeader =it,TotalAmount  = it.InvoiceLine.Sum(t=>t.LineAmount)}); return invoiceHeaderModellist;});
    return View(data);
}
```

In this action i don't think you required to include 'Include(i => i.Customer).Include(i => i.CustomerBranch)' if required you can add before where closure.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this.

Comment: Having trouble getting this working. It seems the line of code populating applicationDbContext populates it with a single InvoiceHeaderModel, not any kind of list, so the ToListAsync() method wont compile, as a single object cannot be turned into a list.

Comment: Hi @Shaggs I edited it for list of InvoiceHeaderModel try this.. and update

Comment: may be you need to change the async task to normal task.. and remove return View(applicationDbContext);

Comment: Hi @shaggs async Task issue resolved can you please check

Comment: Thanks.Two problems now: 1) I get a null exception from this code. I suspect its because the invoicelines (InvoiceHeader.InvoiceLInes) are not populated. 2) It wont let me return View(data), as it is a list<InvoiceHeaderModel>, and cant be assigned to a IEnumerable<InvoiceHeader>

Comment: Sorry if it seems I'm trying to get someone to write my code for me. I'm new to both ASP.NET and entity framework, so learning the right way to do things in this environment is a bit of a learning curve for me.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work it out. Saneesh's suggestion was close, but not quite what I wanted.

The code I ended up using is:

```
// GET: InvoiceHeaders

public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    ApplicationUser appUser = ConstantData.GetApplicationUser(_context, _userManager.GetUserId(User));
            var applicationDbContext = _context.InvoiceHeader.Include(i => i.Customer).Include(i => i.CustomerBranch)
                .Where(i => i.CustomerID == appUser.CustomerID)
                .Select(i => new InvoiceListViewModel
                {
                    invoiceHeader = i,
                    TotalAmount = i.InvoiceLines.Sum(t => t.LineAmount)
                });
    return View(await applicationDbContext.ToListAsync());
}
```

Thanks for your help Saneesh.