# Calculate sum of decimal values from child class and display in parent class in one to many relationships in asp.net core web api

Tags: sum, asp.net-core-webapi

I am still new to asp.net core web api one to many relationships, I have two tables: Loan and loanHistories

Loan Model

```
public class Loan
{
    [Key]
    public int LoanID { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [Column(TypeName = "money")]
    public decimal LoanAmount { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [Column(TypeName = "money")]
    [Display(Name = "Loan Balance")]
    private decimal _LoanBalance;
    public decimal LoanBalance
    {
        get
        {
            
            return LoanAmount *interestRate;
        }
        set { _LoanBalance = value; }
    }
    
    [Display(Name = "Interest Rate")]
    public decimal interestRate { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Application Date")]
    public DateTime ApplicationDate { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Disbursement Date")]
    public DateTime DisbursmentDate { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Due Date")]
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Defaulted")]
    public bool Defaulted { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Approved")]
    public bool Approved { get; set; }

    //Navigation property
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public Customer customer { get; set; }

    //public ICollection<LoanComments> loancomments { get; set; }
    public ICollection<LoansHistories> loansHistories { get; set; }
       


}
```

LoanHistories model:

```
public class LoansHistories
{
    [Key]
    public int HistID { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [Column(TypeName = "money")]
    [Display(Name = "Repaid Amount")]
    public decimal RePaidIn { get; set; }
   
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Repayement Date")]
    public DateTime RepayementDateDate { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "No of paying interest only")]
    public int NoOfPayinyingIntrestOnly { get; set; }
    //Navigation properties

    public int LoanID { get; set; }
    public Loan loan { get; set; } 

}
```

It generates the following Json data

```
[{"loanID":1,"loanAmount":1000.0000,"loanBalance":15000.000000,"interestRate":15.00,"applicationDate":"2022-03-28T00:00:00","disbursmentDate":"2022-03-28T00:00:00","dueDate":"2022-04-28T00:00:00","defaulted":false,"approved":true,"customerID":30290122,"customer":null,"loansHistories":[{"histID":1,"rePaidIn":500.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-03-28T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":1,"loanID":1},{"histID":4,"rePaidIn":2000.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-03-21T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":1,"loanID":1},{"histID":5,"rePaidIn":50000.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-03-28T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":1,"loanID":1},{"histID":6,"rePaidIn":50000.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-03-28T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":5,"loanID":1},{"histID":7,"rePaidIn":50000.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-03-28T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":1,"loanID":1},{"histID":8,"rePaidIn":50000.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-03-28T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":1,"loanID":1},{"histID":10,"rePaidIn":200.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-03-28T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":8,"loanID":1}]},{"loanID":2,"loanAmount":3000.0000,"loanBalance":45000.000000,"interestRate":15.00,"applicationDate":"2022-03-28T00:00:00","disbursmentDate":"2022-03-28T00:00:00","dueDate":"2022-03-28T00:00:00","defaulted":false,"approved":true,"customerID":30290122,"customer":null,"loansHistories":[{"histID":2,"rePaidIn":2000.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-03-08T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":1,"loanID":2},{"histID":9,"rePaidIn":50000.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-03-28T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":2,"loanID":2}]},{"loanID":3,"loanAmount":1000.0000,"loanBalance":150.000000,"interestRate":0.15,"applicationDate":"2022-03-28T00:00:00","disbursmentDate":"2022-03-28T00:00:00","dueDate":"2022-03-28T00:00:00","defaulted":false,"approved":true,"customerID":30290122,"customer":null,"loansHistories":[]},{"loanID":4,"loanAmount":2000.0000,"loanBalance":2300.000000,"interestRate":1.15,"applicationDate":"2022-03-28T00:00:00","disbursmentDate":"2022-03-28T00:00:00","dueDate":"2022-03-28T00:00:00","defaulted":false,"approved":true,"customerID":30290122,"customer":null,"loansHistories":[{"histID":3,"rePaidIn":2000.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-03-28T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":1,"loanID":4},{"histID":11,"rePaidIn":2000.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-03-28T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":3,"loanID":4},{"histID":12,"rePaidIn":2000.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-03-28T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":6,"loanID":4},{"histID":13,"rePaidIn":2000.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-03-28T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":6,"loanID":4},{"histID":14,"rePaidIn":2000.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-02-27T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":7,"loanID":4},{"histID":15,"rePaidIn":2000.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-03-28T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":1,"loanID":4},{"histID":16,"rePaidIn":2000.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-03-14T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":6,"loanID":4},{"histID":17,"rePaidIn":2000.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-03-28T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":3,"loanID":4},{"histID":18,"rePaidIn":2000.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-03-22T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":8,"loanID":4}]},{"loanID":5,"loanAmount":1000.0000,"loanBalance":1150.000000,"interestRate":1.15,"applicationDate":"2022-03-28T00:00:00","disbursmentDate":"2022-03-29T00:00:00","dueDate":"2021-04-29T00:00:00","defaulted":false,"approved":true,"customerID":30290122,"customer":null,"loansHistories":[]},{"loanID":8,"loanAmount":3000.0000,"loanBalance":3450.000000,"interestRate":1.15,"applicationDate":"2022-04-25T00:00:00","disbursmentDate":"2022-03-28T00:00:00","dueDate":"2022-04-26T00:00:00","defaulted":false,"approved":true,"customerID":30290122,"customer":null,"loansHistories":[]},{"loanID":9,"loanAmount":1000.0000,"loanBalance":1150.000000,"interestRate":1.15,"applicationDate":"2022-04-13T00:00:00","disbursmentDate":"2022-04-04T00:00:00","dueDate":"2022-04-25T00:00:00","defaulted":false,"approved":true,"customerID":30290122,"customer":null,"loansHistories":[]},{"loanID":10,"loanAmount":3000.0000,"loanBalance":3450.000000,"interestRate":1.15,"applicationDate":"2022-04-19T00:00:00","disbursmentDate":"2022-04-26T00:00:00","dueDate":"2022-04-25T00:00:00","defaulted":false,"approved":true,"customerID":40140676,"customer":null,"loansHistories":[{"histID":1012,"rePaidIn":300.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-04-05T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":1,"loanID":10},{"histID":1013,"rePaidIn":150.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-04-19T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":2,"loanID":10},{"histID":1014,"rePaidIn":300.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-04-11T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":3,"loanID":10},{"histID":1015,"rePaidIn":150.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-04-11T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":4,"loanID":10},{"histID":1016,"rePaidIn":300.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-04-06T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":5,"loanID":10},{"histID":1017,"rePaidIn":150.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-04-04T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":6,"loanID":10},{"histID":1018,"rePaidIn":300.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-04-05T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":7,"loanID":10},{"histID":1019,"rePaidIn":150.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-04-19T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":8,"loanID":10},{"histID":1020,"rePaidIn":150.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-04-02T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":9,"loanID":10},{"histID":1021,"rePaidIn":150.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-04-04T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":10,"loanID":10},{"histID":1022,"rePaidIn":100.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-04-06T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":12,"loanID":10},{"histID":1023,"rePaidIn":350.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-04-04T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":13,"loanID":10},{"histID":1024,"rePaidIn":100.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-04-12T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":14,"loanID":10},{"histID":1025,"rePaidIn":350.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-04-11T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":6,"loanID":10},{"histID":1026,"rePaidIn":100.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-04-20T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":14,"loanID":10},{"histID":1027,"rePaidIn":1000.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-04-12T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":16,"loanID":10},{"histID":1028,"rePaidIn":1000.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-04-04T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":17,"loanID":10},{"histID":1029,"rePaidIn":1000.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-04-04T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":18,"loanID":10}]},{"loanID":11,"loanAmount":1000.0000,"loanBalance":1150.000000,"interestRate":1.15,"applicationDate":"2022-04-26T00:00:00","disbursmentDate":"2022-04-25T00:00:00","dueDate":"2022-04-05T00:00:00","defaulted":false,"approved":true,"customerID":30290122,"customer":null,"loansHistories":[{"histID":1030,"rePaidIn":150.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-04-05T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":1,"loanID":11},{"histID":1031,"rePaidIn":150.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-04-12T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":5,"loanID":11}]},{"loanID":12,"loanAmount":1000.0000,"loanBalance":1150.000000,"interestRate":1.15,"applicationDate":"2022-04-24T00:00:00","disbursmentDate":"2022-04-24T00:00:00","dueDate":"2022-04-25T00:00:00","defaulted":false,"approved":true,"customerID":40140676,"customer":null,"loansHistories":[{"histID":1032,"rePaidIn":150.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-04-04T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":1,"loanID":12},{"histID":1033,"rePaidIn":150.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-03-28T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":3,"loanID":12}]},{"loanID":13,"loanAmount":2000.0000,"loanBalance":2300.000000,"interestRate":1.15,"applicationDate":"2022-04-24T00:00:00","disbursmentDate":"2022-04-25T00:00:00","dueDate":"2022-05-03T00:00:00","defaulted":false,"approved":true,"customerID":30290122,"customer":null,"loansHistories":[{"histID":1034,"rePaidIn":300.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-03-28T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":1,"loanID":13},{"histID":1035,"rePaidIn":300.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-04-12T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":9,"loanID":13}]},{"loanID":14,"loanAmount":1000.0000,"loanBalance":1150.000000,"interestRate":1.15,"applicationDate":"2022-04-25T00:00:00","disbursmentDate":"2022-04-06T00:00:00","dueDate":"2022-04-26T00:00:00","defaulted":false,"approved":true,"customerID":30290122,"customer":null,"loansHistories":[{"histID":1036,"rePaidIn":150.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-04-05T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":1,"loanID":14},{"histID":1037,"rePaidIn":1000.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-04-04T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":4,"loanID":14},{"histID":1038,"rePaidIn":150.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-04-18T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":4,"loanID":14},{"histID":1039,"rePaidIn":1000.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-04-11T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":5,"loanID":14},{"histID":1040,"rePaidIn":100.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-04-19T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":6,"loanID":14},{"histID":1041,"rePaidIn":50.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-04-04T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":7,"loanID":14},{"histID":1042,"rePaidIn":50.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-04-05T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":8,"loanID":14},{"histID":1043,"rePaidIn":50.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-04-06T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":8,"loanID":14},{"histID":1044,"rePaidIn":1000.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-03-28T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":89,"loanID":14}]},{"loanID":1014,"loanAmount":5000.0000,"loanBalance":5750.000000,"interestRate":1.15,"applicationDate":"2022-03-28T00:00:00","disbursmentDate":"2022-04-11T00:00:00","dueDate":"2022-04-12T00:00:00","defaulted":false,"approved":true,"customerID":40140676,"customer":null,"loansHistories":[{"histID":2035,"rePaidIn":750.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-04-11T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":1,"loanID":1014},{"histID":2036,"rePaidIn":1000.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-04-12T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":2,"loanID":1014},{"histID":2037,"rePaidIn":750.0000,"repayementDateDate":"2022-03-30T00:00:00","noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":3,"loanID":1014}]}]
```

Now I want to calculate the total sum of rePaidIn within loanHistories table and display in loan table Has TotalRepaidIn with heading [NotMapped]: I have tried from the following link .[it seems close to answer my question but it does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47386256/entity-framework-calculate-sum-field-from-child-records)
Here is my Controller

```
 [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Loan>>> Getloans()
    {
        return await _context.loans.Include(lh => lh.loansHistories).ToListAsync();
    }
```

Any solution will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a whole working demo:

Model:

```
public class Loan
{
    [Key]
    public int LoanID { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [Column(TypeName = "money")]
    public decimal LoanAmount { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [Column(TypeName = "money")]
    [Display(Name = "Loan Balance")]
    private decimal _LoanBalance;
    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2)")]
    public decimal LoanBalance
    {
        get
        {
            return LoanAmount * interestRate;
        }
        set { _LoanBalance = value; }
    }
    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2)")]
    [Display(Name = "Interest Rate")]
    public decimal interestRate { get; set; }
    //....
    [Display(Name = "Approved")]
    public bool Approved { get; set; }
    //public ICollection<LoanComments> loancomments { get; set; }
    public ICollection<LoansHistories> loansHistories { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public decimal TotalRepaidIn { get; set; }    //add this...
}
public class LoansHistories
{
    [Key]
    public int HistID { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [Column(TypeName = "money")]
    [Display(Name = "Repaid Amount")]
    public decimal RePaidIn { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Repayement Date")]
    public DateTime RepayementDateDate { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "No of paying interest only")]
    public int NoOfPayinyingIntrestOnly { get; set; }
    public int LoanID { get; set; }
    public Loan loan { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Loan>>> Getloans()
{
    var data = await _context.loans.Include(lh => lh.loansHistories).Select(l=>new Loan() 
    { 
        TotalRepaidIn = l.loansHistories.Select(lh=>lh.RePaidIn).Sum(),
        loansHistories = l.loansHistories,
        ApplicationDate = l.ApplicationDate,
        Defaulted=l.Defaulted,
        DisbursmentDate= l.DisbursmentDate,
        DueDate= l.DueDate, 
        LoanID=l.LoanID,
        Approved=l.Approved,
        interestRate=l.interestRate,
        LoanAmount=l.LoanAmount
    }).ToListAsync();
    return data;
}
```

**Update:**

A better way is to change your model like below:

```
using System.Linq;  //import this namespace...
public class Loan
{
    [Key]
    public int LoanID { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [Column(TypeName = "money")]

    public decimal LoanAmount { get; set; }

    private decimal _TotalRepaidIn;
    [NotMapped]
    public decimal TotalRepaidIn
    {
        get { return loansHistories.Sum(sum => sum.RePaidIn); }
        set { _TotalRepaidIn = value; }
    }
    //other properties
    public ICollection<LoansHistories> loansHistories { get; set; } = new List<LoansHistories>();  

}
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Loan>>> Getloans()
{
    return await _context.loans.Include(lh => lh.loansHistories).ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Rena, I have one more Question then I will be okey with my project

Comment: Please Refer to this Link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71749482/loading-data-from-three-related-tables-in-asp-net-core-using-entity-framwork-cor

Comment: Hi @isaackiplagat, Let me check.

Comment: Please do , where you need clarity let me know, Thanks in advance @Rena

Comment: Hi @isaackiplagat, I found it seems the similar question. And I found an easier way to achieve your requirement. You can check it.

Comment: Thanks @Rena, it works fine and I am happy for the easier way coz it applies to both Customer and Loans