# Loading data from three related tables in ASP.NET Core using Entity Framwork Core in one-to-many relationship makes some data not displayed

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have three tables `Customer`, `Loan` and `LoanHistories`. `Customer` table is related to `Loan` table in a one-to-many relationship, and the `Loan` table is related to `LoanHistories` in one-to-many relationship as well.

The following are the C# classes for these tables:

```
public class Customer
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [Display(Name = "ID NO")]
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
    public string PhoneNo { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Nearest Primary School")]
    public string NearestPrimarySchool { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Photo")]
    public string Photo { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Loan> loans { get; set; }
    // public IEnumerable<LoansHistories> loansHistories { get; set; }
   // public ICollection<WorkForLiving> workForLivings { get; set; }
   // public ICollection<CustomersCharacterBehavior> customersCharacterBehaviors { get; set; }
}

public class Loan
{
    [Key]
    public int LoanID { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [Column(TypeName = "money")]
    public decimal LoanAmount { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public decimal TotalRepaidIn { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [Column(TypeName = "money")]
    [Display(Name = "Loan Balance")]
    private decimal _LoanBalance;

    public decimal LoanBalance
    {
        get { return LoanAmount * interestRate; }
        set { _LoanBalance = value; }
    }
    
    [Display(Name = "Interest Rate")]
    public decimal interestRate { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Application Date")]
    public DateTime ApplicationDate { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Disbursement Date")]
    public DateTime DisbursmentDate { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Due Date")]
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Defaulted")]
    public bool Defaulted { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Approved")]
    public bool Approved { get; set; }

    //Navigation property
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public Customer customer { get; set; }

    //public ICollection<LoanComments> loancomments { get; set; }
    public ICollection<LoansHistories> loansHistories { get; set; }
}

public class LoansHistories
{
    [Key]
    public int HistID { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [Column(TypeName = "money")]
    [Display(Name = "Repaid Amount")]
    public decimal RePaidIn { get; set; }
   
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Repayement Date")]
    public DateTime RepayementDateDate { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "No of paying interest only")]
    public int NoOfPayinyingIntrestOnly { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    public int LoanID { get; set; }
    public Loan loan { get; set; }

    // Navigation property
    // public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    // public Customer customer { get; set; }
}
```

This is the `LoansController` that loads data from `Loans` and `LoansHistories` tables:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Loan>>> Getloans()
{
    var data = await _context.loans
                             .Include(lh => lh.loansHistories)
                             .Select(l => new Loan()
        {
            TotalRepaidIn = l.loansHistories.Select(lh => lh.RePaidIn).Sum(),
            Balance = l.loansHistories.Select(lh => lh.RePaidIn).Sum()-l.LoanAmount,
            loansHistories = l.loansHistories,
            ApplicationDate = l.ApplicationDate,
            Defaulted = l.Defaulted,
            DisbursmentDate = l.DisbursmentDate,
            DueDate = l.DueDate,
            LoanID = l.LoanID,
            Approved = l.Approved,
            interestRate = l.interestRate,
            LoanAmount = l.LoanAmount
        }).ToListAsync();

    return data;
}
```

This is the data in JSON format:

```json
[
   {
      "loanID":1,
      "loanAmount":1000.0000,
      "totalRepaidIn":202700.0000,
      "balance":201700.0000,
      "loanBalance":15000.000000,
      "interestRate":15.00,
      "applicationDate":"2022-03-28T00:00:00",
      "disbursmentDate":"2022-03-28T00:00:00",
      "dueDate":"2022-04-28T00:00:00",
      "defaulted":false,
      "approved":true,
      "customerID":0,
      "customer":null,
      "loansHistories":[
         {
            "histID":1,
            "rePaidIn":500.0000,
            "repayementDateDate":"2022-03-28T00:00:00",
            "noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":1,
            "loanID":1,
            "loan":null
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I want to load data from customer controller but I found entity TotalRepaidIn to be Zero, How can I make it return a value has its returning in loan controller? without having entity totalRepaidIn":0.0

Customer controller:

```
  // GET: api/CustomersApi
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Customer>>> Getcustomers()
    {
        return await _context.customers.Include(l=>l.loans).ThenInclude(h=>h.loansHistories).ToListAsync();
    }
```

It returns the following Json data:

```json
[
   {
      "customerID":30290122,
      "firstName":"Isaac",
      "lastName":"Kiplagat",
      "phoneNo":"0724797768",
      "nearestPrimarySchool":"Mokwo",
      "photo":"photo",
      "loans":[
         {
            "loanID":1,
            "loanAmount":1000.0000,
            "totalRepaidIn":0.0,
            "balance":0.0,
            "loanBalance":15000.000000,
            "interestRate":15.00,
            "applicationDate":"2022-03-28T00:00:00",
            "disbursmentDate":"2022-03-28T00:00:00",
            "dueDate":"2022-04-28T00:00:00",
            "defaulted":false,
            "approved":true,
            "customerID":30290122,
            "loansHistories":[
               {
                  "histID":1,
                  "rePaidIn":500.0000,
                  "repayementDateDate":"2022-03-28T00:00:00",
                  "noOfPayinyingIntrestOnly":1,
                  "loanID":1
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is like the previous did you can select the new Customer instance and set value for it one by one.

Another easier way, you can change your property to below to calculate the `RePaidIn`:

```
using System.Linq;  //import this namespace...
public class Loan
{
    [Key]
    public int LoanID { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [Column(TypeName = "money")]

    public decimal LoanAmount { get; set; }

    private decimal _TotalRepaidIn;
    [NotMapped]
    public decimal TotalRepaidIn
    {
        get { return loansHistories.Sum(sum => sum.RePaidIn); }
        set { _TotalRepaidIn = value; }
    }
    //other properties
    public ICollection<LoansHistories> loansHistories { get; set; } = new List<LoansHistories>();  
}
```

And in your `LoansController`, you can improve the action to below:

```
var data = await _context.loans.Include(lh => lh.loansHistories).ToListAsync();
```

Customer Controller can also get the correct value for `TotalRepaidIn`.

Comment: Hello @rena, please show the other way of selecting the customer instance, the other option of changing properties in model works only in geting data, it becomes problematic when posting data, it complains of null entities, "System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')'
"

Comment: Your help will be highly appreciated

Comment: The issue caused by null value of loansHistories you post. You need set initial value for it `public ICollection<LoansHistories> loansHistories { get; set; } = new List<LoansHistories>(); `. Then you need modify the TotalRepaidIn to specify the getter setter. Otherwise you can not get the post value. I have modify my code above, and you can see you will receive the value for `_TotalRepaidIn` field.